# React Native MapView: undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, undefined, react-proptypes

I am a beginner in React Native and I am trying to use the MapView component from the 'react-native-maps' module.

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  AppRegistry,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';


export default class LocationDisplay extends Component<{}> {

  render() {
    return (
      <MapView/>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('LocationDisplay', () => LocationDisplay)
```

I am getting this error:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating ‘_react.PropTypes.string’)
```

Can Anyone Help me?

Answer (score 0):

`PropTypes` used to be included in React, but is now a separate package.

```
npm i prop-types
```

Changes from:

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
```

to

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

Example usage:

```
class Item extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        data: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    };
}
```